# function start even though its not called

Tags: android, firebase, service

I have a service(triggered when I select a slot) in my app that starts a timer and at the end of the that timer (onFinish()) calls a function(called database2) that will check the database if the slot passed to my service is "vacant" "occupied" or "reserved". If the slot is "reserved" it will change it to vacant. The problem is that after reserving the same slot for the second time the function database2 automatically checks if the slot is vacant or not. It runs even though it is not called yet. I used shared preference to pass the name of the slot to the service that will be reserved.

here's my code

Timer inside the service and the database 2:

```
 public void DurationTimer(final String slot){
        final long dur = 30000;
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(dur,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long millis= millisUntilFinished;
                String hms= String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",

                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))
                        //seconds
                        ,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
                );
                startForeground(uniqueID, buildForegroundNotification(hms));
                database1();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                database2(slot);
                Toast.makeText(TimerService.this, "onFinish", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                long n[] = {1,5000};
                v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v.vibrate(n, -1);
                endnotif();
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
    }
```

database2 function:

```
 public void database2 (final String slot)
    {
        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("parking_lot");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final String key = ds.getKey();

                    DatabaseReference keyReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("parking_lot").child(key);
                    keyReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String value = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue(String.class);
                            if (key.equals(slot)) {
                                if (value.equals("occupied")) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(TimerService.this,"occupied (service)"+slot,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();onDestroy();
                                } else if (value.equals("reserved")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(TimerService.this,"vacate: "+slot,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                                    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("parking_lot");
                                    final DatabaseReference myRef1 = myRef.child(slot);
                                    final DatabaseReference myRef2 = myRef1.child("status");
                                    myRef2.setValue("vacant");
                                } else if (value.equals("vacant")) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(TimerService.this,"vacant (service)"+slot,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, "Read ok");
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Read failed");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Read failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method database2() is not being called the second time, but onDataChange() do.

That is because you have set a value event listener to the database reference in such a way that it will invoke each time a value change occurs in there.

### The solution

Use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead of `addValueEventListener()`

Comment: I'll try this solution.

Comment: Hello sir thanks for the naswer but the problem is still there. I changed 

keyReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 

this line of code to:

keyReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()

but picking the same slot still automatically change the slot to "vacant"

Comment: Have you changed "myRef.addValueEventListener()" too?